# Recurrent Relation Problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am having trouble finishing this problem for finding a recurrent relation. The problem is:

$T(n)=8T(n/2) + n^3$, $T(1)=1$ ; find $T(n)$

So I am using iteration to generate a general formula for the equation and have managed to get to the following point after performing three iterations:

$8^3T(n/2^3) + n^3 + n^3+ n^3$

I make this out to be:

$8^kT(n/2^k) + n^3(1+1+1+.... 1^k-1)$

From here I struggle and do not quite know how to proceed to find the answer. If anyone can help me it would be much appreciated.

Comment: T(0) doesn't seem to fit with the recurrence relation

Comment: T(0) is all that was given, T(1) was not given.

Comment: Substitute $n=0$ into your equation. You get $7=0$. This problem has no solution

Comment: Either you copied it wrong, or whoever gave it to you is wrong.

Comment: Well maybe the question maker made an error then?

Comment: Doesn't matter. This question as posed has no answer. If you would like to know the general method of solving such problems, try to give a different initial condition

Comment: Ok I am going to edit the initial condition. I edited the initial condition to T(1)=1. Does that make is solvable now?

Comment: Should be. I don't have much experience with such recurrences. Try to explicitly generate a few terms (such that they are numbers) and see what the sequence looks like.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Make a change of variable:

$$n=2^m \\ T(n)=a(m)$$

This means that:

$$\frac{n}{2}=2^{m-1}$$

Then you should substitute it into the initial equation:

$$\begin{array}( T(n) & = & 8 T \left(\frac{n}{2} \right) &+&n^3 \\ \downarrow & ~ &  ~\downarrow & ~ & \downarrow \\ a(m) & = & 8 a \left(m-1 \right) &+&2^{3m} \end{array}$$

Now you get a linear recurrence:

$$a(m)=8 a(m-1)+8^{m}$$

Do you know how to solve it?

Further hint:

Consider another sequence:

$$a(m)=8^{m} b(m)$$

Comment: I am honestly lost at this point. I do not know how to get past the linear recurrence part,

Comment: @NoobCoder, what do you get after using my last hint? What does the recurrence for $b(m)$ look like?

Comment: What does b(m) equal?

Comment: @NoobCoder, substitute the expression for $a(m)$ in terms of $b(m)$ I have written into the recurrence equation for $a(m)$ I have obtained. Show me what you get, then I will answer your question

Comment: Would I be doing $a(m)/8^m$ ?

Comment: @NoobCoder, I have got the following equation $a(m)=2^3 a(m-1)+2^{3m}$ (do you understand how I did it?). Now I suggest you define the new sequence according to $a(m)=8^{m} b(m)$. Take the right hand side of the previous and put it into the recurrence relation *instead of* $a(m)$. Then simplify the result

Comment: I do not understand how you did it. What was the original formula?

Comment: @NoobCoder, I am not going to give you the final answer. Your lack of understanding suggest to me that you didn't properly train yourself on more simple recurrence problems. You should do that before moving on to the more complicated ones. But I will show in detail how I've got the relation for $a(m)$. $$ $$ I recommend the book "Concrete Mathematics: A Foundation for Computer Science" [here's a pdf](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf) which has a full explanation on how to deal with recurrences, lots of examples and exercises

Comment: So wait are you saying to set up the following equation? $2^3a(m-1)+2^3m=8^mb(m)$

Comment: @NoobCoder, that's not what you get after the substitution and simplification. You've made a mistake somewhere

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. It isn't that I properly did not train myself. I have spent hours trying to learn this material and I have really struggled with it.

Comment: @NoobCoder, I have really enjoyed that book I linked, I believe Knuth and the other authors specifically intended it as a mathematics introduction for computer science students. Another advice, if you will bear with me: if you just want to get an answer to such problems, use https://www.wolframalpha.com/ : it solves linear recurrences if you enter them in the same notation as above. It will give you the answer you seek, but without the steps (unless you get a subsctiption for pro version)

Answer (score 0):

When proceeding with master theorem relations $$T(bn)=a\,T(n)+f(n)$$

You can try to find a simpler relation either

- $U(n)=a\dfrac{T(n)}{n^\alpha}$
- $V(n)=a\dfrac{T(n)}{n^\alpha}+c\dfrac{f(n)}{n^\alpha}$

with a suitable choice of $\alpha$ (depends on what $f(n)$ looks like...)

See for example some instances of the second method here : [solving recurrence equations and get complexity T(n)...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2533578/solving-recurrence-equations-and-get-complexity-tn/2533708#2533708)

But sometimes it does not work and first method is preferable.

Here we have $$T(2n)=8T(n)+8n^3$$

If you try second method on this relation ( e.g. $V(n)=8\dfrac{T(n)}n+cn^2$ ), you will get nowhere, you cannot find a suitable $c$ that works.

In this case first method works fine :

Let set $U(n)=\dfrac{8T(n)}{n^3}$

Then $U(2n)=\dfrac{T(2n)}{n^3}=8\dfrac{T(n)}{n^3}+8=U(n)+8$

We have found a simpler relation $$U(2n)=U(n)+8$$

It solves to $U(2^m)=U(1)+8m$

which is equivalent to $U(n)=U(1)+8\dfrac{\ln(n)}{\ln(2)}=U(1)+8\log_2(n)$

Finally you deduce $T(n)=\dfrac{n^3U(n)}{8}=n^3(C+\log_{2}(n))$