# Solve $T(n) = 16T(n/2)+2n^4$ using the Master Theorem

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, recurrence-relations, computer-science

I am struggling to find a constant that satisfies the regularity condition.
$\log_ba$ gives me $4$ which $n^4$ is smaller than $f(n)$ so I thought it's the third case of the Master Theorem but apparently it's not. Also, I tried multiplying my formula by $1/2$ which I don't even know if possible and leads me nowhere.

Comment: I'll set another sequence $S(n)=\frac{T(n)}{n^4}$. Then following holds...

$$
S(n)=\frac{T(n)}{n^4}=\frac{16T(\frac n2)}{n^4}+2=\frac{T\left(\frac n2\right)}{\left(\frac n2\right)^4}+2=S\left(\frac n2\right)+2
$$

Comment: @Nightflight I didn't understand. What got you the set another sequence and how do I proceed from the point you shown?

Comment: This is a standard method when dealing with equations like this, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3002925/399263, he did the "U" transform presented in my post. A follow up is then to set $n=2^p$ to get to a telescopic $f(p)-f(p-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Without master theorem.

As

$$
T\left(2^{\log_2 n}\right)=16T\left(2^{\log_2 \frac n2}\right)+2n^4
$$

calling $\mathcal{T}\left(\cdot\right)=T\left(2^{(\cdot)}\right)$ and $z = \log_2 n$ we follow with

$$
\mathcal{T}\left(z\right)=16\mathcal{T}\left(z-1\right)+2\cdot 2^{4z}
$$

with solution

$$
\mathcal{T}\left(z\right)=16^{z-1}c_0 + 2^{4z+1}z
$$

and now going backwards with $z=\log_2 n$ we get

$$
T(n) = \frac {1}{16}n^4\left(c_0+32\log_2 n\right)
$$